# Longest sequence with only moves to draw without a repetition

Tags: endgame, draw, tablebases, records

What is the longest known sequence of moves with upto 6 pieces where each move of
 both sides is the only move drawing the game (any other move would lose the game) ?

There should not occur any repitition of a position.

I experimented with the endgame rook vs two (three) pawns and got some
 sequences I unfortunately do not remember.

Comment: I truly wish (but doubt) that this is true of the starting position.

Comment: The starting position may well be a draw, but I highly doubt that all starting moves but one are a forced win for Black :)

Answer (score 3):

To get the ball rolling, from the following position the first 6 moves for each side are forced in order not to lose. (If `7.h8=B` weren't available and `7.h8=Q` needed to be played, then the forced follow-ups `7...h1=Q+ 8.Qxa1+ Kxa1` would extend it to 8, but no cigar.)

```
[FEN "K5R1/8/p7/8/8/7P/8/1q1k4 w - - 0 1"]

1.Rg1+ $1 Kc2 $1 2.Rxb1 $1 Kxb1 $1 3.h4 $1 a5 $1 4.h5 $1 a4 $1 5.h6 $1 a3 
$1 6.h7 $1 a2 $1 7.h8=Q 
    ( 7.h8=B )
7...a1=Q+ $1 8.Qxa1+ $1 Kxa1 $1 *
```

Comment: already pretty good!

Comment: Don't you get half a cigar if you replace the BPa6 by a bPd6 ? Then 7.h8Q and 7...d1Q are forced too.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Matplus.net forums,](http://matplus.net/start.php?px=1584295518&app=forum&act=posts&fid=xshowm&tid=2324) Arpad Rusz shared the longest such sequence in a 6-piece position. The length of it is 19 plies.

You can check the uniqueness for yourself by using the [Sygyzy tablebases.](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=3k4/8/8/p4pP1/3K3P/8/8/8_w_-_-_0_1).

```
[FEN "3k4/8/8/p4pP1/3K3P/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. h5 Ke7 2. h6 Kf7 3. Ke5 Kg6 4. Ke6 f4 5. h7 Kxh7 6. Kf7 f3 7. g6+ Kh6 8. g7 f2 9. g8=Q f1=Q+ 10. Ke7
```

Answer (score -1):

do you mean this position?

```
2Q5/8/8/8/3n4/8/1b6/k2K4 b - - 0 1
```

Comment: No, BOTH sides must have only one move to draw.